# Deleting Tree-Nodes in a SQL table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to write a recursive procedure that would delete the node and all it's children if they are such in the table. I tried doing the following

```
  CREATE PROCEDURE DeleteFile 
    @FileID INTEGER,
    @UserID VARCHAR(MAX) 
AS
    DELETE FROM [FileTree] WHERE [ID] = @FileID AND [UserID]=@UserID;
    IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [FileTree] WHERE [ParentID] = @FileID AND [UserID]=@UserID)
    BEGIN
       DECLARE FileCursor CURSOR LOCAL FOR 
            SELECT [ID],[UserID] FROM [FileTree] WHERE [ParentID] = @FileID AND [UserID]=@UserID;
       OPEN FileCursor 
       FETCH NEXT FROM FileCursor INTO @FileID , @UserID 
       WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS =0
       BEGIN
            EXEC DeleteFile @FileID,@UserID;
            FETCH NEXT FROM FileCursor INTO @FileID , @UserID ;
       END
    END
    ELSE
    return
```

But for some reason this is not working. It deletes the node but the kids remain.
Table ,,design" .

```
CREATE TABLE [FileTree] (
    [ID]       INT           IDENTITY  NOT NULL,
    [Name]     VARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    [ParentID] INT           NULL,
    [UserID]   VARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL
);
```

Can you please indicate the errors I made and suggest a working procedure ? 
UPD: I made the cursor LOCAL and I am fetching one time before going into the while loop, it still does not delete all the children.

Comment: I don't know why yours isn't working, but I'd look into using a recursive CTE to get all the IDs under the parent, and delete from the table where the ID is in the CTE.   Google "recursive CTE" for lots of examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have syntax problem.i fixed it like this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DeleteFile 
    @FileID INTEGER,
    @UserID VARCHAR(MAX) 
AS
BEGAIN
    DELETE FROM [FileTree] WHERE [ID] = @FileID AND [UserID]=@UserID;
    IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [FileTree] WHERE [ParentID] = @FileID AND [UserID]=@UserID)
    BEGIN
       DECLARE FileCursor CURSOR LOCAL FOR 
            SELECT [ID],[UserID] FROM [FileTree] WHERE [ParentID] = @FileID AND [UserID]=@UserID;
       OPEN FileCursor 
       FETCH NEXT FROM FileCursor INTO @FileID , @UserID 
       WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS =0
       BEGIN
            EXEC DeleteFile @FileID,@UserID;
            FETCH NEXT FROM FileCursor INTO @FileID , @UserID ;
       END
    END
  END
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a CTE and a temporary table:

```
WITH CTE (ID)
AS
(
    SELECT ID FROM FileTree WHERE Id=@ID
    UNION ALL
    SELECT t.ID FROM FileTree t
    INNER JOIN CTE c ON t.ParentId=c.Id
)
SELECT ID INTO #temp FROM CTE;


DELETE FROM FileTree WHERE ID IN(SELECT ID FROM #temp)
DROP TABLE #temp
```

Comment: Wait but how is the recursion supposed to be organized ? Do I create the temporary table after checking for the existence of kids and  use the code that you wrote and it will delete all the children and their children ? If you explain how does this work it would be really helpful.

Comment: The recursion is done by the CTE then The CTE inserts IDs of the node itself and its children into #temp. At the end we can use #temp to delete the nodes we want to be deleted.