# Deleting Tree-Nodes in a SQL table without a cursor

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a tree of strings stored in a sql table, this is the definition for the table.

```
CREATE TABLE [FileTree] (
    [ID]       INT           NOT NULL,
    [Name]     VARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    [ParentID] INT           NULL,
    [UserID]   VARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL
);
```

And I have a recursive delete procedure for deleting a node and it's children, it uses a cursor and it  works perfectly well after a user on SO in my previous question regarding this matter pointed out the problems with the syntax. ([Deleting Tree-Nodes in a SQL table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26865939/deleting-tree-nodes-in-a-sql-table))

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DeleteFile 
    @FileID INTEGER,
    @UserID VARCHAR(MAX) 
AS
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM [FileTree] WHERE [ID] = @FileID AND [UserID]=@UserID;
    IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM [FileTree] WHERE [ParentID] = @FileID AND [UserID]=@UserID)
    BEGIN
       DECLARE FileCursor CURSOR LOCAL FOR 
            SELECT [ID],[UserID] FROM [FileTree] WHERE [ParentID] = @FileID AND [UserID]=@UserID;
       OPEN FileCursor 
       FETCH NEXT FROM FileCursor INTO @FileID , @UserID 
       WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS =0
       BEGIN
            EXEC DeleteFile @FileID,@UserID;
            FETCH NEXT FROM FileCursor INTO @FileID , @UserID ;
       END
    END
  END
```

However , another reply to the question suggested using a Common Table Expression, I googled and I don't think I really understand how can a CTE replace the cursor in this procedure. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a recursive CTE to get all children of the ID that should be deleted and then use that in a DELETE statement:

```
with all_ids as (
  select id, ParentID
  from FileTree
  where id = 4  -- this is the root ID that should be deleted

  union all

  select c.id, c.ParentID
  from FileTree c
    join all_ids p on p.id = c.ParentID
)
delete from file_tree
where id in (select id from all_ids);
```

SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ef474f/1

Comment: So 4 is the ID of the node you want to delete and in my case that is where the parameter is going ? And btw, what's all_ids supposed to be ?

Comment: Correct, `4` is the ID you want to delete. `all_ids` is the (recursive) common table expression that builds up the hierarchy of all child nodes.